# Store the value generated by PROC FREQ

Tags: sas

The PROC Freq function generates a frequency table with the percentage, and the frequency of the variables. Is there a way to store the percentage of the variable for later use (like use this value to create dataset, create graphs)?

Comment: See the documentation https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_freq_syntax08.htm

Answer (score 0):

`ODS OUTPUT` is your friend any time you want to take the results of a PROC.  Many procs, including `PROC FREQ`, also have output options built-in, but the generic one is `ODS OUTPUT`.

First, use `ODS TRACE` to identify the (internal to SAS) name of the table you need.

```
ods trace on;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;
ods trace off;
```

This generates:

```
Output Added:
 -------------
 Name:       OneWayFreqs
 Label:      One-Way Frequencies
 Template:   Base.Freq.OneWayFreqs
 Path:       Freq.Table1.OneWayFreqs
 -------------
```

Now you can use that with `ods output`:

```
ods output OneWayFreqs=myfreqdata;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables age;
run;
ods output close;   *this is technically not needed, but I like to have it for clarity;
```

It will make a table called `myfreqdata` (name that something useful please!).  It isn't always "pretty"; sometimes you are better off using the built in output options in a proc, because they're more usefully formatted, but usually you can get somewhere from it.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

It sounds like you want to output the results of the PROC FREQ to a SAS dataset. This will allow you to use them later, whether it is for further analysis or visualization. To do that, simply pass the a dataset name to the `out=` option after the `table` statement. You will notice below I also used the `noprint` option. This avoids needlessly printing the table.

For example,

```
proc freq data=work.dataset noprint;
    table var1*var2 / out=work.output_data;
run;
```

I hope this helps!